# android studio 2.2.1 cannot resolve symbol *

Tags: android-studio

I use android-studio 2.1.1 in the past, yesterday I downloaded android-studio 2.2.1, but found cannot resolve symbol error, now I use android-studio 2.1.1 and everything is ok, I have already tried :

```
1、File->Invalidata Caches/Restart->Invalidata and Restart
2、Build->Make Module
3、Build->Make Project
4、Build->Clean Project
5、Build->Rebuild Project
```

can anyone help me , thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is a bug, so submit to google, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210688&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as you. Google released android studio 2.2 preview 2 today - I downloaded and tried it, and it solves this problem.

Comment: No, I tried it moment ago and found it still not solved, my os is ubuntu 14.04 and jdk version is 1.8.0_92, how about you ?