# Android studio 2.2 Cannot resolve symbol 'FragmentPagerAdapter'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I have a project that is working perfectly on Android Studio 2.1 but when I updated to Android Studio 2.2 it stopped resolving `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` I don't know why

I tried the project on Android Studio 2.1 again and it still working fine.
I tried to import settings from old to new Studio but this didn't solve it.
What's preventing Android Studio 2.2 from resolving `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` ?

I have already tried :

```
1、File->Invalidata Caches/Restart->Invalidata and Restart
2、Build->Make Module
3、Build->Make Project
4、Build->Clean Project
5、Build->Rebuild Project
```

I saw this question [android studio 2.2.1 cannot resolve symbol *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336960/android-studio-2-2-1-cannot-resolve-symbol) but I already have android studio 2.2 preview 2 and it didn't solve the issue.

This is my build.grade file for the app module :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    }
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.COMPILE_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'club.androidy.callcontrolfree'
        minSdkVersion project.MIN_SDK
        targetSdkVersion project.TARGET_SDK_VERSION
        versionName project.VERSION_NAME
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }


    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile(name:'DuappsAd_CW_Online_v1.0.4.2', ext:'aar')
    compile 'com.github.codechimp-org.apprater:library:1.0.+'
    compile project(':SlidingTab')
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.arclayout:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: The build is a preview, so it might have some bugs, do not expect stable quality from a preview build

Comment: @invariant Thank you, so the solution is to wait for a stable version. OK we are waiting :)

Comment: another thing you can do is fill a bug report, if you think that indeed something's wrong with the build, start from here: http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs

Comment: Could you please post your build.grade file for the app module? The file that starts with: `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: @krislarson I posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it stopped resolving `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`

That's because you have the v4 support library, not v13:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
```

Change your imports from `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`

– or –

Change your library to `compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.3.0'`

Comment: But why version 2.1.1 resolved it when 2.2 didn't? I didn't change anything at all.

Comment: The upgrade shouldn't have changed the app's gradle build file, but it's possible that it did. Hard to say.

Comment: If it did why it worked fine on 2.1.1 after that without any modifications from me? I don't think this is the case. Thank you very much :)